# PHP value in an array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I'm working on a checking a given array for a certain value.

my array looks like

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $positions[] = array( 'pos' => $row['pos'], 'mark' => $row['mark'] );
}
```

I'm trying to get the info from it with a method like

```
<?php
    if(in_array('1', $positions)){
          echo "x";
    }
?>
```

This I know the value '1' is in the array but the x isn't being sent as out put. any suggestions on how to get "1" to be recognized as being in the array?

Edit:
I realize that this is an array inside of an array. is it possible to combine in_array() to say something like:
"is the value '1' inside one of these arrays"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in_array is not recursive.  You're checking if 1 is in an array of arrays which doesn't make sense.  You'll have to loop over each element and check that way.

```
$in = false;
foreach ($positions as $pos) {
    if (in_array(1, $pos)) {
        $in = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`in_array` only checks the first level. In this case, it only sees a bunch of arrays, no numbers of any kind. Instead, consider looping through the array with `foreach`, and check if that `1` is where you expect it to be.

Answer (score 1):

That's because $positions is an array of arrays (a multi-dimensional array).
It contains no simple '1'.

Try a foreach-loop instead:

```
foreach($postions as $value)
    if ($value["pos"] == '1')
        echo "x ".$value["mark"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `1` isn't actually in the array. It's in one of the `array`'s within the array. You are comparing the value `1` to the value `Array` which obviously isn't the same.

Something like this should get you started:

```
foreach ($positions as $position) {
    if ($position['pos'] == 1) {
        echo "x";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array `$positions` is recursive, due to the fact that you use `$positions[]` in your first snippet. `in_array` is not recursive (see the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)). Therefore, you need a custom function which works with recursive arrays ([source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#107821)):

```
<?php
function in_arrayr( $needle, $haystack ) {
    foreach( $haystack as $v ){
        if( $needle == $v )
            return true;
        elseif( is_array( $v ) )
            if( in_arrayr( $needle, $v ) )
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}
?>
```

Instead of calling `in_array()` in your script, you should now call `in_arrayr()`.